# Dynamically change view column names in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

My data is as below

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', 'A|36~Batman', 'A|37~Superman', 'A|38~Aquaman'],
  ['01/08/2018', 950, 654, 123],
  ['02/08/2018', 760, 786, 423],
  ['03/08/2018', 1121, 856, 632],
  ['04/08/2018', 842,  475, 257],
  ['05/08/2018', 948,  658, 324]
]);
```

While plotting this chart in the graph, I want to show the label values split after the '~' sign i.e. (Batman, Superman, Aquaman). I need the values before the tilde during the OnClick event of my chart so I need those values in the data as my onclick code is as below

```
var col = chart.getSelection()[0]['column'];
var Id = data.getColumnLabel(col).substr(0, data.getColumnLabel(col).indexOf("~"));
```

So to fetch data, I need the Id values as well. I was able to loop the columns and modify the column label values, but I don't know the code to set the column label as new values. My code to loop is as below

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
for (var i = 0; i < view.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    var ColumnName = view.getColumnLabel(i);
    var NewColumnName = ColumnName.substring(ColumnName.lastIndexOf('~'), ColumnName.length)
    // set new column name in the view
}
```

How to replace the old column name with the new column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use method --> `setColumnLabel`

however, this method does not exist on the view,
so you'll have to change the column label on the data table

since the view is based on the data table,
the view pick up the new label as well...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
for (var i = 0; i < view.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    var ColumnName = view.getColumnLabel(i);
    var NewColumnName = ColumnName.substring(ColumnName.lastIndexOf('~'), ColumnName.length)
    data.setColumnLabel(i, NewColumnName);
}
```

**EDIT**

instead of using the label to store two values,
take advantage of the properties available on the column.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', {id: 'A|36', label: 'Batman'}, {id: 'A|37', label: 'Superman'}, {id: 'A|38', label: 'Aquaman'}],
  ['01/08/2018', 950, 654, 123],
  ['02/08/2018', 760, 786, 423],
  ['03/08/2018', 1121, 856, 632],
  ['04/08/2018', 842,  475, 257],
  ['05/08/2018', 948,  658, 324]
]);
```

then you can use methods --> `getColumnId()` & `getColumnLabel()`

if that isn't enough, you can provide your own custom properties...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', {id: '36', label: 'Batman', p: {category: 'A'}}, {id: '37', label: 'Superman', p: {category: 'A'}}, {id: '38', label: 'Aquaman', p: {category: 'A'}}],
  ['01/08/2018', 950, 654, 123],
  ['02/08/2018', 760, 786, 423],
  ['03/08/2018', 1121, 856, 632],
  ['04/08/2018', 842,  475, 257],
  ['05/08/2018', 948,  658, 324]
]);
```

then use method --> `getColumnProperty(1, 'category')`

Comment: As I said, if my data table column name is replaced, during my OnClick event, I wont get the Id of the clicked object which is before the '~'. Also I bind my chart using `chart.draw(view, options);` as I need to show labels on the charts as well. Any other option?